# JS reg ex for month date

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using simple indx which uses JS regex.
They say that %date% variable is the same as regex

```
    (((J(anuary|uly|une))|February|(M(arch|ay))|(A(pril|ugust))|((Sept|Nov|Dec)ember)|October)|
    (jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec))[.,]{0,1}[\s]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2}[.,]{0,1}[\s]{0,1}(19|20|)\d\d| 
    (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9])(th|rd|st|nd){0,1}[\s]{0,1}(day\s){0,1}(of\s){0,1}(((J(anuary|uly|une))|February|
    (M(arch|ay))|(A(pril|ugust))|((Sept|Nov|Dec)ember)|October)|(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec))[.,]{0,2} 
     [\s]{0,1}(19|20|)\d\d| (0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9])[- /.](19|20|)\d\d|(0[1-9]|
     [12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])[- /.](19|20|)\d\d|(19|20|)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])[-  
     /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9])
```

But that doesn't work. 
I need to have it capture the dates in numbers or numbers and month name
This is what I have so far, but can't seem to figure out how I capture 5 may 2012

For nummeric dates

```
(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d|(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

For month name (but incomplete. Should be i.e 5 may 2012)

```
(?<Month>((Jan(uary)?)|(Feb(ruary)?)|(Mar(ch)?)|(Apr(il)?)|(May)|(June?)|(July?)|(Aug(ust)?)|(Sep(t(ember)?)?)|(Oct(ober)?)|(Nov(ember)?)|(Dec(ember)?)))\s*[ ,-]\s*(?<Date>(([12][0-9])
```

Can anybody advice

Comment: Are you sure Regex is the only way?

Comment: Last time I wrote a date parser in JS, I used my regex to pull out a word in the month position and used a map that took month names as the index of a map that returned the month number. I put the month name in canonical form (lower case) and both the full name and the short name.

Comment: yes. the manual states js regular expression only. (or variable but this can't be done as it uses a different langauge)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (more understandable, I hope) regex that works for cases like yours:

```
var monthsWords = "(jan(uary)?|feb(ruary)?|mar(ch)?|apr(il)?|may|june?|july?|aug(ust)?|sep(tember)?|oct(ober)?|nov(ember)?|dec(ember)?)";
var monthsNos = "((0?[1-9])|1[0-2])";
var months = "(("+monthsWords+")|("+monthsNos+"))";
var days = "((0?[1-9])|([12][0-9])|(3[0-1]))";
var years = "\\d{4}";
var separator = "[. /-]";
var pattern = months + separator + days + separator + years;
var regexp = new RegExp(pattern, "i");
regexp.compile(regexp); 
var result=regexp.test("May 4 2012");
```

Of course, if you need more flexibility (e.g. reverserd order of months and days) you need to modify the pattern. Also, I assumed any four digit string is a valid year, you might need to modify it as well. Note the use of the "i" flag to make the pattern case insensitive.